# Rails change_column removing index from schema

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I am trying to make it so certain columns cannot be null. I use `change_column` no problem but some of these columns have an index attached to them signifying that it is unique.

However when I run this migration:

```
change_column :users, :username, :string, null: false
change_column :users, :email, :string, null: false
change_column :users, :password, :string, null: false
change_column :users, :terms_agreed, :boolean, null: false
```

It removes the `add_index` in the schema

**schema.rb**

```
- add_index "users", ["username"], :name => "index_users_on_username_code", :unique => true
- add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email_code", :unique => true
add_index "users", ["confirmation_code"], :name => "index_users_on_confirmation_code", :unique => true
```

How do I do this without removing the indexes?

P.S. its not actually removing the indexes in the database. Just in the `schema.rb` file.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of how migrations are treated depends on you database implementation. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732896/does-rename-column-take-care-of-indexes), but in your migration you should explicitly request an index in your `change`.

```
class DoSomethingToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :username, :string, null: false, index: true
  end
end
```

See the docs for more [information](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns).

Answer (score 0):

So still unclear as to what happened, but turns out that the indexes got deleted from the database during some database manipulation.

I just put the schema back the way I needed it to be and ran `rake db:setup` then my migration again and everything worked fine. Very confusing and a lot of unnecessary time spent trying to figure it out.