# How to fix 'ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed' when changing column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a Rails web app. I have a table called `countries` that is associated with two other tables: `cities` and `sites`. When I try to change the column `code` to `name` in the `countries` table, I get the following exception:

> ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE "countries"

I have tried adding the `dependent: :destroy` thing, but I still get the same exception. I tried dropping the table, and recreating it, and still not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Country` model:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :cities, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :sites, dependent: :destroy

    has_many_attached :photos

    validates :code, uniqueness: true
    validates :about, presence: true

end
```

Here is the migration code I'm using to change the name of the column in the `countries` table:

```
class FixCodeName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
def change
    rename_column :countries, :code, :name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you attempting to rename the column? With a migration like the following?

```
class ChangeColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    rename_column :countries, :code, :name
  end
end
```

If you drop your whole database you can edit your older migrations and then recreate it. That's what I usually do if it's early in the development process.

Comment: Yes, through a migration. I am in early stages of the development of my app, but I'm tired of dropping my who database every time something goes wrong or I want to make a small change.

Comment: I don't understand why your code is trying to DROP TABLE "countries" to rename a column. Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: My code is not trying to DROP TABLE "countries", I am not sure why such alleged action is mentioned in the exception text.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your migration code to it? Maybe that will give us a clue.

Comment: I believe you're getting this error because there's an index on column code. Can you remove the index then try to run the migration?

Comment: How do I remove the index?

Comment: To get the information for the table countries, use the following command from the sqlite command line:     .schema countries, then DROP INDEX index_name.

Comment: You could also try to remove it in a migration by using remove_index :countries, column: :code

Comment: The migration was successful (and I assumed it removed the index, I'm not sure). But the column name change still returns the same exception.

Comment: If you run out of ideas, I will just do what you suggested in the first place; to drop the entire database.

Comment: I would fire up the sqlite cli to check if the index got removed. The clue I'm going off of is from the answer of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732896/does-rename-column-take-care-of-indexes. I recommend using a different database for development because Sqlite does not always behave like the other options.

Comment: @InsolentWorm old versions of sqlite didn't support renaming columns. The workaround involved copying data to a new table, dropping the original, and renaming the new one. This naturally doesn't play well with foreign keys referring to the column in question. Dealing with that is *really* ugly (see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). The ORM might not even attempt to try.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I solved it by deleting `fix_code_name` migration and then editing the migration that created the `countries` table then finally running `rails db:drop:_unsafe db:create db:migrate`.

Comment: I've chosen your answer, but I will edit your answer to reflect what I've done.